# push hash ref into array ref perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

i am fetching data from a database...what i would like to achieve is for every data row fetched(id,title) to create a hash ref

```
{
   id => data->[0],
   title => data[1]
}
```

and push this hash ref into array ref in order to create the following format

```
 {  category => [
                   {
                    id => 1,
                    title => "title1"
                   },
                   {
                   id => 2,
                   title => "title2"
                   }
                  ]
              }
```

what i have made:

```
   my $productCategories->{category} = [];
    my $product = {};
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq[SELECT id,title FROM ].DB_SCHEMA().qq[.product_categories]) || die $dbh->errstr;
    $sth->execute() || die $dbh->errstr;
    while(my $data = $sth->fetch){
        $product =  {
                    id      =>  $data->[0],
                    title   =>  $data->[1]
                    };
        push $productCategories->{category}, $product;
    }
```

but it is not working...

Comment: See also [using push() on an array inside a hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007154/perl-using-push-on-an-array-inside-a-hash/34007666#34007666)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn on `use strict;` `use warnings;` and it'll tell you why.

> push on reference is experimental
>
> Not an ARRAY reference

Try:

```
push @{$productCategories->{category}}, $product;
```

Also: Be careful with declaring things you're `push`ing outside the loop - you should be ok in this case, but bear in mind you're pushing a reference. If you re-use variables, you *can* end up with pushing the same reference.

Comment: Does in my sample.  But perhaps you need to be clearer what you mean by 'not working'.

Comment: using warn Data::Dumper::Dumper(@{$productCategories->{category}}); i am getting this response: 'id' => 2
        };
$VAR3 = {
          'title' => 'pizza',
          'id' => 3
        };
$VAR4 = {
          'title' => "\x{396}\x{3c5}\x{3bc}\x{3b1}\x{3c1}\x{3b9}\x{3ba}\x{3ac}",
          'id' => 4
        };

Comment: You need to pass a ref to `Data::Dumper`. `print Dumper $productCategories` should do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

DBI has many methods for fetching data. One of them is called [`fetchall_arrayref()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchall_arrayref) and it will give you back the data in exactly the structure that you need - no need to build it up yourself.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq[SELECT id,title FROM ] .
                        DB_SCHEMA() .
                        qq[.product_categories])
  || die $dbh->errstr;

$sth->execute() || die $dbh->errstr;

# Pass a hash ref to get each row back as a hash.
$productCategories->{category} = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
```